# Downloading conan packages from artifactory: Which hash belongs to which package version?

Tags: cmake, artifactory, conan

my company deployed a conan package at their artifactory server. There are several versions of this package available for different configurations. Let's say there are two versions, one for Ubuntu and one for Debian. The urls of these versions are looking like this:

```
https://artifactory.<my-company>/artifactory/<the-project-depending-on-the-conan-package>/_/<name-of-the-package>/<version-number-of-the-package>/_/0/package/<THE-HASH-FOR-UBUNTU-VERSION>/0/conan_package.tgz
https://artifactory.<my-company>/artifactory/<the-project-depending-on-the-conan-package>/_/<name-of-the-package>/<version-number-of-the-package>/_/0/package/<THE-HASH-FOR-DEBIAN-VERSION>/0/conan_package.tgz
```

When we build a project, which depends on this package, we need to download the fitting version of it (Ubuntu or Debian). Unfortunately, these downloads need to happen during the build (we use cmake).

Now my question: As you can see, the urls contain the hash of the package versions. But when I build the project, how do I now which hash is for the Ubuntu or the Debian version? Obviously I need to distinguish between the two hashes to download the fitting package-version.
Note: Please assume that my conan-cache is empty.

I hope you guys can help my and please correct my if I there are any missunderstandings (I am new to cmake, conan and artifactory).

Comment: You can't do it based on that hash, because it settings + options + dependencies to calculate. Instead, as you are Distro dependent, you should add a custom setting, related to Distro: https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/extending/custom_settings.html, so every package will be SAFE, and you can install according the distribution with no doubt.

Comment: @uilianries "you can install according the distribution" this is excatly the part I'm stuck on. Is there something like a conan command to download and install the fitting conan-package for my system? I need to download the file conan-package.tgz which can be accessed with one of the links I wrote down in my post.

Comment: Do you want to distribute packages, like .tar or .zip? If yes, I recommend you using cmake to package (https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.6/module/CPackDeb.html), then you can use deploy generator to copy locally (https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/devtools/running_packages.html#deployable-packages)